# Black hole and metric background

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor

How can I make a black hole by changing a metric background?
I have one metric background that isn't black hole. I want to convert a metric to black hole by changing the coordinates. What should I do?

Comment: Hi @Marja.Kms, welcome to Physics.SE.  Your question is currently quite unclear.  Can you try to explain more thoroughly what you're trying to ask?  For example, by "make a black hole" do you mean the formation of a black hole, or do you mean a mathematical description?

Comment: Hi @DilithiumMatrix, Thanks for your attention. I edited my question.

Comment: Comment to the post (v4): GR is a geometric theory independent of coordinates. Why should physics (i.e. whether there is a black hole or not) change because you change coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

$$g_{\mu \nu} dx^{\mu} dx^{\nu} = \left(1 - \frac{r_s}{r}\right) c^2 dt^2 - \left(1 - \frac{r_s}{r}\right)^{-1} dr^2 - r^2 \left( d\theta^2 + \sin^2 \theta d\varphi^2 \right). $$

This is a "metric background" as you would call it corresponding to the [Schwarzschild geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric). It describes a stationary non-rotating black hole with no electromagnetic charge.